# Let $A,B,C$ in $M_n(\mathbb C).$ Suppose $CA = BC$ and $rank(C) = r$. Show that $A$ and $B$ have at least $r$ eigenvalues in common.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Let $A,B,C$ in $M_n(\mathbb C).$ Suppose $CA = BC$ and $rank(C) = r$.
>   Show that $A$ and $B$ have at least $r$ eigenvalues (counted with
>   multiplicity) in common.

I do not see how to use characteristic polynomial, and minimal polynomial does not give the number of eigenvalues counted with multiplicity. If someone has an hint...

There exist $P$ and $Q$ invertible matrices such that $C = PJ_rQ$ with $J_r$ having first $r$ diagonal coefficients equal to $1$, and $0$ elsewhere.

N.B. : It is supposed to be able to be solved without Jordan reduction since it is not in my curriculum (anyway, it is possible it simplifies the problem).

Comment: I think the problem *may be* easy to solve, if you (without loss of generality) assume that $C$ is in its Jordan form.  I have not tried, but it seems to be a promising idea to me.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If $v$ is a $\lambda$-eigenvector of $A$, then $Cv$ (if non-zero) is a $\lambda$-eigenvector of $B$, since $BCv=CAv=\lambda Cv$. This immediately implies the statement if $A$ is diagonalizable (since a complete basis of eigenvectors of $A$
maps to an $r$-dimensional space of eigenvectors for $B$ under $C$).

Hint 2: If $A$ is not diagonalizable, then we instead do the same tactic with generalized eigenvectors. Suppose $v$ is a generalized $\lambda$-eigenvector of $A$; that is, $v\neq 0$ but $(A-\lambda I)^n v=0$ for some positive integer $n$. Observe that $C(A−\lambda I)^n=(B−\lambda I)^nC$ for any $\lambda,n$, thus if $Cv\neq 0$, then $Cv$ is a generalized $\lambda$-eigenvector of $B$.

Comment: This is what I first thought, but there are two obstructions.  How do you know that $Cv\neq 0$ and how does it help when $A$ is not diagonalizable?

Comment: 1) $Cv$ may be zero; the point is that at least $r$ of them must be non-zero.

2) If $A$ is not diagonalizable, then we instead do the same calculus with generalized eigenvectors using the observation $C(A-\lambda I)^n=(B-\lambda I)^nC$.

Answer (score 1):

Use elementary row/column operations to pick two invertible matrices $U$ and $V$ such that $UCV=I_r\oplus0$. Then
$$
(UCV)(V^{-1}AV)=(UBU^{-1})(UCV).\tag{1}
$$
Partition $V^{-1}AV$ and $UBU^{-1}$ into $2\times2$ block matrices so that their first sub-blocks have the same sizes as $I_r$. What does the equality $(1)$ tell you about the first block row of $V^{-1}AV$ and the first block column of $UBU^{-1}$?